# jquery autocomplete key value not displaying values returned from asmx

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to set key/value list for autocomplete field via asmx web service.

This is the data I'm returning to the jquery:

```
> {   "419": "Alexander High School",   "370": "Alfred I. duPont Middle
> School",   "245": "Allatoona High School",   "120": "Allen D. Nease
> High School",   "365": "Alpharetta High School",   "232": "Andrew
> Jackson High School",   "371": "Apalachee High School" }
```

The way I'm creating the data is:

```
[WebMethod(true)]
        public string GetSchoolList()
        {
            var schItem = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            var schools = UndercBLL.GetSchools().ToList();
            foreach (SchoolItem school in schools)
            {
                schItem.Add(school.Id.ToString(), school.Name);
            }

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(schItem, Formatting.Indented);
            return json;

        }
```

the jquery section is set like this:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "SchoolInfo.asmx/GetSchoolList",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                            response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                                return {
                                    label: value,
                                    value: key
                                };
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2
            });
```

Alerting the data gives me 
[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong? I'm not getting any error in firebug, but as you can see as well, I'm not shown any autocomplete options.

Comment: What is in the `[object Object]` instead of alerting do a `console.log(data);` to see what the object actually contains...

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/c528e68a815f4e383ab68699c0114423.png